# Child wordpress theme breaks site structure on last category pages

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, categories

I am using a child theme I created based off of the Wordpress 2016 theme and I have a category page with a lot of posts to where it creates pagination (because I have only 10 posts per page show) everything works fine until you get to the last few pages and the site begins to break.

I have tried changing the amount of posts you get per page from 5 to 10 and it doesn't seem to change the fact that the last few pages get messed up.

Now I created a custom archive page where I altered the code to display the featured image and excerpt only instead of the whole post.

Here is the code from the archive.php file:

```
get_header('MBH-cat'); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
<div id="city-headlines"><h1><?php
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
echo $category->cat_name . ' '; 
} 
?></h1></div>
    <div id="MBH-blog-roll-cat"><div id="MBH-blog-roll-pad">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>


        <?php
        // Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h2 style="padding-bottom:14px;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?    php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): // check for the featured image ?>
<div class="MBH-excerpt-thumb"><a href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" title="<?    php the_title(); ?>" class="opacity"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div> <!--    echo the featured image-->

<div class="MBH-excerpt-div"><?php
endif;
the_excerpt(); // echo the excerpt
?>
<div class="hr"><hr /></div>
</div>

        <?php
endwhile;
// resets main query
?>
<div style="margin-top:280px;">
<?php
        // Previous/next page navigation.
        the_posts_pagination( array(
            'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentysixteen' ) . ' </span>',
        ) );

    // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
    else :
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif;
    ?></div>
</div>
    </main><!-- .site-main -->
    </div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also, should the:

```
<div class="MBH-excerpt-div">
```

come before the:

```
<div class="MBH-excerpt-div">
```

?

Like:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">

<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <div id="city-headlines">
    <h1>
     <?php
        foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
            echo $category->cat_name . ' '; 
        } 
     ?>
    </h1>
    </div>

    <div id="MBH-blog-roll-cat"><div id="MBH-blog-roll-pad">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

         <?php
            // Start the Loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <h2 style="padding-bottom:14px;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<? php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): // check for the featured image ?>
                 <div class="MBH-excerpt-thumb">
                   <a href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" title="<? php the_title(); ?>" class="opacity">
                     <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                   </a>
                 </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="MBH-excerpt-div"> 
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <div class="hr">
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile;
            // resets main query
            ?>


    </div>

        <div style="margin-top:280px;">
                    <?php
                            // Previous/next page navigation.
                            the_posts_pagination( array(
                              'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'twentysixteen' ),
                              'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'twentysixteen' ),
                              'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentysixteen' ) . ' </span>',
                            ) );
        echo '</div>';

        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
         else :
             get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

         endif; ?>  

</main><!-- .site-main -->
```

Comment: I switched the order of the endwhile; and endif; PHP lines of your example and the page no longer breaks! The only issue I have now is that some of the posts towards the end of the pagination no longer displays the excerpt. Im going to go through those posts to make sure there is no weird formatting or unclosed <div>s

Comment: Turns out that the reason some of the excerpts weren't showing was because the if statement for the featured image was encompassing the excerpt code so it was relying on whether or not there was a featured image to show an excerpt or not. I moved the endif statement up above the 'code'<div class="MBH-excerpt-div">'code' and it fixed everything. I'll edit your answer and move the  'code'<?php endif' ?> 'code'above that div.